# How do I open a directory (folder) then open a file in the directory - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

How do I open a directory (Folder) then open a file in the directory?

Answer (score 0):

you can open the file directly with [open(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)
For Example(1):

```
file = open('file.txt','r')
print(file.read())
file.close()
```

Or if you wish to see all files in a current directory you can see with the help of [OS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module.
For Example(2):

```
import os
dir_list = os.listdir()#for getting all files n folder in the current path
```

it will show all the files n folders name in list format.

Comment: How do I specify the directory to list? Then how do I open the a specific  text file in that directory? Basically I am making and storing announcements and I got them stored in txt files. Then I want to be able to take what is in this text files and make the announcement.

Comment: I cant understand your query properly! So you are going to add several directory to a list and going to open some specific file in any directory that is stored! then going to read them and make the announcement ! right ?